# Regular expression to extract a percentage

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I have strings like the following: `blabla a13724bla-bla244 35%`

Notice that there is always a space before the percentage. I would like to extract the percentage number (so, without the `%`) from these strings using the Linux shell.

Comment: Have you tried `(\d+)%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
echo blabla a13724bla-bla244 35% | sed 's/.*[ \t][ \t]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)%.*/\1/'
```

If you expect to have multiple percentages in a line then:

```
echo blabla 20% a13724bla-bla244 35% | \
   sed -e 's/[^%0-9 ]*//g;s/  */\n/g' | sed -n '/%/p'
```

Comment: this will not work for 100% (pun intended) - only up 2 digits are allowed

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP '\d+(?=%)' <<< "blabla a13724bla-bla244 35%"
35
```

Comment: This is for if the percentage is a decimal, eg 99.99%: `grep -oP '[\.\d]+(?=%)'`

Comment: Although that will match `foo.%`. For arbitrary float numbers, I'd use `[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\d*\.\d+)(?=%)` -- that will ensure you get at least one digit in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
echo "blabla a13724bla-bla244 35%" | cut -d' ' -f3 | sed 's/\%//g'
```

NOTE: Assumption is the input is always in this format and percentage is 3rd token separated by space.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regular expression:

```
/\s(\d+%)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
\s(\d{1,3})%
```

If you need it in shell, you can use sed or this perl one-liner:

```
echo "blah 35%" | perl -pe "s/.*\s(\d{1,3})%/\1/g"
35
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a number of continuous columns maybe you should try with awk instead of a regular expresion.

```
cat file.txt |awk '{print $3}'  |cut -d "%" -f 1
```

With this code you obtain the third column.

Comment: You didn't remove the percent character.

Comment: sorry i'm forgot add the cut command

   cat file.txt |awk '{print $3}'  |cut -d "%" -f 1